# Unable to create room Mozilla hubs room on local system

Tags: mozilla

I am trying to install Mozilla hubs on my local server. I have followed Mozilla hub documentation to install Mozilla hubs on my local system.
I want to customize the hub client.

I followed the below steps :
https://hubs.mozilla.com/docs/hubs-cloud-custom-clients.html

1. Cloned the project  https://github.com/mozilla/hubs
2. Installed the dependencies using npm ci
3. npm run login. see below link

https://imgbox.com/RMDjA2h7

I am confused here that what I should write in the host address.

4. npm run dev
   When I run the command using dev then it doesn't allow me to create a new room in custom Mozilla hubs. see below link

https://imgbox.com/ZWwSzQ5B

Please help me resolve this issue. If I am doing something wrong, please let me know and tell me how can I run Mozilla hubs locally to make some modifications.

Comment: Hi! Can you post the content of your web console? Chances are there's error logs in there that could tell you what's going on.

Comment: Yes, here is screenshot of my console screen                                                                            https://imgbox.com/iTVYpCbH

Answer (score 0):

Host URL is the URL which you get after self hosting mozilla hubs.

You need to deploy a custom client  ([hubs cloud](https://hubs.mozilla.com/cloud) personal / enterprise) in order to get host URL to do login.

And you will only require login if you want to deploy code to custom client. For basic tinkering or to get familiarize with mozilla hubs you need not to  do login

And order to create room you need to do following steps

- clone repo
- `npm ci`
- `npm run dev`

you might need to change your node version for that you can use `nvm`

`nvm` installation guide - https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-version-manager-nvm-install-guide/